# Which Torah and Tanakh is used in Ashkenazi and Sefardi?

Tags: jewish-books

I edit the question a little...

What is the authoritative text/version of the Torah and Kanakh for Ashkenazi and Sefardi Jews? With that I mean, which text do they use when they create a scroll and in their personal studies etc?

I read somewhere it is the *Second Rabbinic Bible* and at another place (much less reliable source) it's *Biblia Hebraica Stuttgartensia*.

Comment: What is the *Second Rabbinic Bible*?

Comment: @sabbahillel It’s a reference to Yaakov b Hayyim’s 1524 edition of Mikraot Gedolot

Comment: @JoelK I thought the question was about a sefer torah, not about a printed edition of *mikraos gedolos*